# Generally I never get insufficient balance error when running anchor test, but sometimes every time I run test It takes all sol with error

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

There was a problem deploying: Output { status: ExitStatus(unix_wait_status(256)), stdout: "", stderr: "" }.

I am using devnet.

Comment: I am using devnet